# Methods to simplify data in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row, simplify

I have a set of 15 data frames dealing with protein sequences and my goal is to analyze the changes in the proteins across time. However, my data frames have about 5000 genes. So I am looking for a way to simplify my data in order for easier analysis.

Below is a sample data frame.

```
> sample
  p1 p2 p3 year
1  a  d  d 1970
2  a  c  e 1970
3  b  d  e 1970
4  b  c  d 1985
5  b  c  d 1985
6  b  c  d 1999
```

What I want to do is analyze each position (`p1` `p2` and `p3`) each year and return the most common entry at that position in that year and thus creating a new data frame with only one sequence per year. The resulting data frame should look like the example below:

```
> result
  p1 p2 p3 year
1  a  d  e 1970
2  b  c  d 1985
3  b  c  d 1999
```

The data frames are already sorted by date, however I do not know how many entries each year have. So, is there a way to simplify my data with this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A data.table solution:

```
dat <- read.table(text=' p1 p2 p3 year
1  a  d  d 1970
2  a  c  e 1970
3  b  d  e 1970
4  b  c  d 1985
5  b  c  d 1985
6  b  c  d 1999',header=TRUE)

library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)

DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x){ y = table(x)
                            names(y)[which.max(y)]}),
   year]

#      year p1 p2 p3
#  1: 1970  a  d  e
#  2: 1985  b  c  d
#  3: 1999  b  c  d
```

#### EDIT another Base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame,by(dat, dat$year, function(x) 
  lapply(x, function(y) { 
    t <- table(y)
    names(t)[which.max(t)]
  })))

#       p1 p2 p3 year
# 1970  a  d  e 1970
# 1985  b  c  d 1985
# 1999  b  c  d 1999
```

Answer (score 3):

With base R functions only, you may solve this as follows.

```
as.data.frame(t(
   sapply(split(sample, sample$year), function(x) {

      # for each x - data frame subset such grouped by year
      apply(x, 2, function(y) { 

          # for each y, i.e. column in x
          t <- table(y)
          names(t)[which.max(t)]  # return the label that occurs most often
      })

   })
))
```

result:

```
##      p1 p2 p3 year
## 1970  a  d  e 1970
## 1985  b  c  d 1985
## 1999  b  c  d 1999
```

Comment: +1 ! because All others solutions are just a rewrite of this one. I suggest the use of `by` to replace `sapply+split` , avoid also `apply` to avoid coercion to characters...see my R base solution above.

Comment: Using this base function gave me an error code saying `In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable` however, the other base R operation (by agstudy) worked perfectly, so I will be working with that one...

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` you could do it like this:

```
require(dplyr)

sample %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(names(which.max(table(.)))))
```

or

```
sample %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(p1 = names(which.max(table(p1))),
            p2 = names(which.max(table(p2))),
            p3 = names(which.max(table(p3))))
```

Result in both cases:

```
#  year p1 p2 p3 
#1 1970  a  d  e
#2 1985  b  c  d
#3 1999  b  c  d
```

The first method is a good choice if you have a lot of columns and you want to do the same operation for all those columns except the grouping variable (year in this case). The second method is appropriate if you have fewer columns. Basically, they do the same thing.

#### Edit

Using `summarise_each` you can also specify columns you either *don't* want to include in the operation or that you want to include (and exclude all other columns). So imagine your sample data had 100 columns p1 ... p100 and you want to do it for all columns except p1 and p3, you could specify:

```
sample %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(names(which.max(table(.)))), -c(p1, p3))
```

The other way round, you could specify to only do it for those two columns:

```
sample %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(names(which.max(table(.)))), p1, p3)
```

And, you can add more functions to the `funs` argument inside `summarise_each`.

Comment: +1 for the use `summarise_each`, worth to mention that you can also combine it with filter in case you want to process to all columns except some ones. I still prefer `.SD` here, it is more flexible :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the data frames I have have different numbers of columns (between 6 and 23) and I think in this case the first method would be easier since I'll since the one code on all data frames